# Why won't Xcode save my change when I try to turn Autoresize Subviews to On/Yes/Checked?

Tags: view, orientation, device, resize, autoresize

I couldn't get all of my views to resize when the device orientation changed.  After comparing with working code from the "page based" template, I finally found that my Views in storyboard needed to have Autoresize Subviews checked.

I did this repeatedly, but every time I would close the project and return, or view the storyboard file as source code, when I returned to view the storyboard the options were unchecked again.

I finally changed the options to "YES" using an external editor.

I found that Xcode would change the option to unchecked (or "NO") and save that selection, but would never allow the option to be checked ("YES") again.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in XCode to me. I'm seeing the same behavior. This was very helpful, though, thanks! I was able to edit the file manually at least to get things working again.

(I actually just deleted the autoresizesSubviews="NO" tags from the offending views entirely rather than setting them to YES.)

Comment: Hm, actually it doesn't seem quite that easy. Sometimes it sticks and sometimes it doesn't when manually editing. Tried both setting to "YES" and deleting attribute entirely.